# AngularJs $window.open not working

Tags: angularjs

I post the data to server and receive data from server , In data, It have a url , then I will open the url in new Tab, but when I use `$window.open(data.url)`  to open ,it is not working

I can not found any error in console ,this is my code

```
$http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : url,
  data    : $.param(formData),  // pass in data as strings
  headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  
})
.success(function(data) {
    $window.open(data.url)
});
```

Comment: Your browser may prevent to open popup window. Chek the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : `$window.open(data.url, '_blank');`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, for me it worked when I changed it to redirect, instead of opening a new window/tab:

```
$window.location.href = data.url;
```

If this does it, then I would say the issue is that the browser is blocking the popup, as it is not opened via direct input from user.

If not, try logging your data object that is returned from the server to ensure that it has URL correctly set in it, and that you actually enter the function.